# Rails 4 has_many :through relationship: assign default value to join model attribute on create action from parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, has-many-through, join

I have three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

***Remark***: I am using Devise for authentication on the `User` model.

The join `Administration` model has the following attributes:

- `id`
- `user_id`
- `calendar_id`
- `role`

Here are my current routes:

```
devise_for :users, :path => 'account'

resources :users do
  resources :calendars
end
```

And here is my `calendars_controller`:

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_calendar, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /calendars
  # GET /calendars.json
  def index
    @user = current_user
    @calendars = Calendar.all
  end

  # GET /calendars/1
  # GET /calendars/1.json
  def show
    @user = current_user
    @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /calendars/new
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @calendar = @user.calendars.new
  end

  # GET /calendars/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  # POST /calendars
  # POST /calendars.json
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @calendar = @user.calendars.new(calendar_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @calendar.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_calendar_path(@user,@calendar), notice: 'Calendar was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @calendar }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @calendar.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /calendars/1
  # PATCH/PUT /calendars/1.json
  def update
    @user = current_user
    @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @calendar.update(calendar_params)
        format.html { redirect_to user_calendar_path(@user,@calendar), notice: 'Calendar was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @calendar }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @calendar.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /calendars/1
  # DELETE /calendars/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = current_user
    @calendar.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_calendars_url, notice: 'Calendar was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_calendar
      @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def calendar_params
      params.require(:calendar).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

My basic CRUD actions are working: once a `user` is logged in, he can `create`, `show`, `edit` and `destroy` a `calendar` that belongs to him.

What I am trying to figure out now, is how to define a default `role` — Owner — in the `Administration` join table when a `user` creates a new `calendar`.

I was considering adding the following line of code to `Calendars#Create`:

```
current_user.add_calendar_and_role(@calendar.id, 'Owner')
```

but I am not sure this is a good practice.

Instead, shouldn't I define a `make_owner` method in my `administration` model and use it with a callback in the `Calendars#Create` action?

Should I also implement `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in my `calendar` model?

Or is there an even better solution that I am forgetting about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general - move code to the model when you can.  Keep your controllers simple.

I don't think you need accepts nested attributes.  I tend to use that when my models are truly child objects, not just joined.

Your datamodel looks good - I think whatever you choose, you'll be able to improve it later or handle more special cases.  That said, I do this sort of thing

```
class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_validation :set_default_role

  def set_default_role
    existing_owner = where(:calendar_id => calendar_id, :role => :owner).exists?
    if existing_owner?
      self.role ||= :standard
    else
      self.role ||= :owner
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And thanks for your advice on placing code in model rather than controller. Back to your answer: I am not sure I understand the `if else` part. Here, what I want to do, is to set a default role when a calendar is created: so their cannot be any previous role set for an instance that has just been created. Am I right or am I just missing the point? (Could be the latter, I am not very experienced with Rails.) Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: No, your right.  There may be an existing calendar and administration, not the same user.  The goal is to have the first one be an admin, otherwise, it's a standard role. Adjusting...

Comment: I am not sure, but I would say it is the other way around: there is a user (the `current_user`) and he creating a new calendar, thus creating a new administration.

Comment: Ok, so maybe we should go with something like: `before_validation :set_default_role` and then `def set_default_role @administration.role = "Owner" end` . What do you think? Maybe you could update your code so I can accept your answer, couldn't you?

Comment: You wouldn't want to make the second administration an Owner.  There can be two administrations on the same calendar, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. Thank you very much for your help.